# Read HTTP POST from mobile in java

Tags: java, ios

I have iOS Swift code, which sends a POST request to server. If i send this code directly to apple server i get response back with proper data. But when i send this to my server, server could not get the body of the HTTP POST.

I have no idea whether this issue is related to client side or server side.

Here is the Swift code.

```
func validateReceipt(completion : (status : Bool) -> ()) {

        let receiptUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL!

        if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(receiptUrl.path!)
        {
            if let receipt : NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: receiptUrl)
            {
                let receiptdata: NSString = receipt.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed)

                let dict = ["receipt-data" : receiptdata]

                let jsonData = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions(rawValue: 0))

                let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: ReceiptURL.MAIN_SERVER.rawValue)!)

                let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
                request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
                request.HTTPBody = jsonData

                let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

                    if let dataR = data
                    {
                        self.handleData(dataR, completion: { status in

                            completion(status: status)
                        })
                    }
                })

                task.resume()
            }
            else
            {
                completion(status: false)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            completion(status: false)
        }
    }
```

and here is my Java code in server side, there are two Java classes which take care of this

```
MyRequestWrapper.Java

package webservice;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.servlet.ServletInputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;

public class MyRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
     private final String body;
     public MyRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
       super(request);
       StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
       BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
       try {
         InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
         if (inputStream != null) {
           bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
           char[] charBuffer = new char[100000];
           int bytesRead = -1;
           while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
             stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
           }
         } else {
           stringBuilder.append("");
         }
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           throw ex;
       } finally {
         if (bufferedReader != null) {
           try {
             bufferedReader.close();
           } catch (IOException ex) {
             throw ex;
           }
         }
       }
       body = stringBuilder.toString();
     }

     @Override
     public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
       final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes());
       ServletInputStream servletInputStream = new ServletInputStream() {
         public int read() throws IOException {
           return byteArrayInputStream.read();
         }
       };
       return servletInputStream;
     }

     @Override
     public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
       return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getInputStream()));
     }

     public String getBody() {
       return this.body;
     }
    }
```

And here is the another class.

```
GetResult.Java

package webservice;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

@Path("/service")
public class GetResult {
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GetResult.class);
    // @Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    //@Produces("text/plain")
    @POST
    @Produces (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response inapp(@Context HttpServletRequest request,
            @Context HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("response===" + response);
        System.out.println("Request-Header===" + request.getHeader("receipt-data"));
        System.out.println("Request===" + request.getParameter("receipt-data"));
        // System.out.println("Request==="+request.getReader());
        // reader(request,response);
        // getBody(request);
        doFilter(request,response);
        String result = "";
        result = " " /* jsonObject */;
        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();

    }
```

We could get the client IP and client Port from this request but unable to get the body. In production also we could not get the body. Some Java developers told me that you cant directly get the raw bytes in Java, i don't know about this.

Somebody please take a look at this, and tell me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Where is the code that writes back response ?

Comment: The response code is there, but the response code will work only if POST data body correctly enters server side. But it does not.

Comment: I think you need an @Consumes("application/json") annotation on the JAX-RS resource class. Put it right above the @Produces annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to explicitly set the content type of the input post body you send to the server. This can be achieved as follows:

```
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

Set the content type after setting the http method and son data to the request object( NSMutableURLRequest object)

This may help you!

Edited:
Actually the header field name is "Content-Type".